# trouble subsetting r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame that amongst its columns are a person (pid) and location columns. I am trying to subset the data so that when a persons ID occurs more than 67 times I take a subset of the data based on the location that person's instances occur in and then run a series of regressions on that subset.

I know how to get everybody who hits that 67 threshold (using table() to get the count of each pid), but how do I then get a subset of the data frame based on their location not knowing what the location is? The data frame has roughly 100,000 rows with 400 people hitting that 67 mark, so doing it by hand doesn't seem practical.

I don't know how to put a sample dataset of my data on here, but it looks something like this. So for example, if pid value 1 repeats 200 times, I'd like to subset all of the data frame that has location value of '6' regardless of the pid. Similar for pid 3 - I'd want all rows where location is '1'. The only catch is that sometimes a a pid will have more than one location. The majority will be in one particular location - so with pid 3, there is location 1 and location 2. In that case I would want to subset the location that has the majority.

```
 pid     location
 1       6
 1       6
 1       6
 2       4
 2       6
 3       1
 3       2
 3       1
```

Sample Data

```
set.seed(1)
pid <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)
location <- sample(1:10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(pid, location)
```

Edits:
Ok - What I'm trying to do is get every Pid that repeats more than 66 times. Once I have that list I want to then see what location they occurred in. Then, I want to run a bunch of regressions on a location subset of the whole dataframe. So - if Pid 1 occurs 500 times, and they occurred in Location 6 I want to subset the dataframe for location 6, create a dummy variable for Pid 1 and run a bunch of regressions on that subset of location 6 (other regression variables not included in this sample). There are 1272 unique Pid in the dataframe. I was able to use the answer from Ano to get what I was looking for, but I did it a little differently in the end. It seemed easier (at least conceptually for me) to first subset the data by location, then get the Pid's that repeat more than 66 times and run my regressions. That eliminated any worry about Pid's that have more than one location. But being pretty new to r, I'm open to other suggestions on what would be a better way to code it.
Hopefully this clarifies it a little.

Comment: You should clarify what your desired output looks like.

Comment: wait - I know I'm new to stackoverflow, but why does a post get put on hold after an answer has already been accepted? Going to edit post now to hopefully make it more understandable.

Comment: You've had five answers, three of which were deleted by their authors because they realized they weren't sure what you were after. The fact that the accepted answer guessed your intent correctly doesn't improve the question in that regard. Maybe it deserves to be reopened now that you've added a further wall of text, but I don't see the point. I'd say just try to be clearer the next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
```

Group the data by PID, count how many instances there are of that PID, filter out those that reach whatever threshold you are interested in and then select select the distinct PIDs

```
foo <- df %>%
  group_by(pid) %>%
  filter(n() >= 67 & max(n() == n())) %>%
  distinct(pid) %>%
  .$pid
```

Use that newly generated vector to subset your original dataframe and select the unique `location`s

```
unique(df[df$pid %in% foo,"location"])
```

Comment: For the second part, they want only one location per pid, sounds like.

Comment: got it. added a `filter(count==max(count))`, I think that should do it

Comment: There is no need for mutate, we can put filters together, last 2 rows can be replaced with `.$pid`...

Comment: Also, you might want to use `%in%` instead of `==` on the last `unique()` function.

Comment: thanks, made those changes. although when trying to explain things with dplyr, I favor more verbose, easier to learn from

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility without the use of `dplyr`:

```
df.freq <- addmargins(table(df), margin = 2)
df.freq <- subset(df.freq, 'Sum' > 67, select = -Sum)

df.max <- apply(df.freq, 1, function(x) {
   names(x)[which(x == max(x))] })
df.max <- unique(as.numeric(df.max))
subset(df, location %in% df.max)
```